# insert a time value in oracle

Tags: oracle, date, time

I create a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE flights_info 
( flight_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  Train_no number(10) NOT NULL,
  station varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  depature_time date NOT NULL,
  arrival_time date NOT NULL,
  seats_number number(10) NOT NULL, 
  seats_reserved number(10) NOT NULL, 
 flight_date date NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT flight_id PRIMARY KEY (flight_id )
);
```

the fileds depature_time and arrival_time should represent time values
so I tried to insert using this script

```
INSERT INTO flights_info (flight_id,Train_no,station,depature_time,arrival_time,seats_number,seats_reserved,flight_date) VALUES
(1,1,'Station01', to_date('8:00','hh:mi'),to_date('10:00','hh:mi'),30,10, date '2022-05-14');
```

but I don't why I got date data instead of time.

Output
[outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRarL.png)

I'm not sure what is wrong

Comment: Oracle doesn't have a time-only data type; and the date data type always has both date and time components. If you do `select to_char(depature_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from flights_info` you will see that the time is there. If you don't provide the date elements then they default to the first day of the current month. Why do you want a separate `flight_date` column, rather than storing the complete start and end date and time? Apart from anything else that would make it easier to deal with flights that span midnight.

Comment: Hi Alex Poole and thanks for the reply, 
I need to separate the flight_date from the time so I can have query about the flights on the last 4 hour .. etc. 
and I don't know how to write one with to_char function

Comment: That sort of query is exactly why you’d store the date and time together. What if you wanted to know data from the last 4 hours at 2am? To_char is for formatting the date for display

Comment: thanks Andrew for clarification , 
I think I will remote the flight_date column , 
But how can I display only time on the query, 
I don't want to select the date,

Comment: You can display only time on the query using TO_CHAR(flight_date,'hh:mi')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DATE` data type is a binary data type that consists of 7 bytes representing: century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** has all of those components even when you only set the some of those components then the others will have the default values set.

- Current year and month.
- First day of the month.
- Zero hours, minutes and seconds.

So if you use:

```sql
SELECT to_date('8:00','hh:mi') FROM DUAL;
```

Then you will get the date that is the 1st day of the current month and year with 8 hours AM and zero minutes and seconds.

> I don't why I got date data instead of time.

Because the client application you are using to display the `DATE` value is set to display only the date component and not the time component of the `DATE`.

For SQL*Plus and SQL Developer, the default format is set by the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter which you can change using:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

For other client applications you will need to look at their preferences (or documentation) to find how the default date format is set.

If you want to only **display** the time component then use:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(arrival_time, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS arrival_time
FROM   flight_info;
```

*Note: the `HH` or `HH12` format models are for a 12-hour clock. You probably want `HH24` for a 24-hour clock.*

---

If you want to store a time without a date then use an `INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND(0)` data type.

```sql
CREATE TABLE flights_info(
  flight_id      number(10) NOT NULL,
  Train_no       number(10) NOT NULL,
  station        varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  depature_time  INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND(0) NOT NULL,
  arrival_time   INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND(0) NOT NULL,
  seats_number   number(10) NOT NULL, 
  seats_reserved number(10) NOT NULL, 
  flight_date    date NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT flight_id PRIMARY KEY (flight_id )
);
```

Then:

```sql
INSERT INTO flights_info (
  flight_id,
  Train_no,
  station,
  depature_time,
  arrival_time,
  seats_number,
  seats_reserved,
  flight_date
) VALUES (
  1,
  1,
  'Station01',
  INTERVAL '08:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,
  INTERVAL '10:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,
  30,
  10,
  date '2022-05-14'
);
```

However, while that might look like a good idea, you probably do want use dates and times so that when a flight spans two-or-more days then you can record the arrival and departure date and time (and you won't need the `flight_date` column as it will be stored in the `arrival_time` and `departure_time` columns).

Comment: thanks all for answering , 
I found the right solution for my case with your answers. 
thanks for all of you again